# Is it possible to conditionally render grandchildren with logic from a HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a HOC that can conditionally render grandchildren, and possibly even further nested children in React.

```
<HOC>
  <Child>
    <Grandchild1/>
    <Grandchild2/>
  </Child>
</HOC>
```

In this example, for instance, some logic inside the HOC decides that Grandchild1 shouldn't be rendered. Getting to this result is easy:

```
<HOC>
  <Grandchild2/>
</HOC>
```

But as you can see, this also skips the `Child` component. However, the endresult I want is this:

```
<HOC>
  <Child>
    <Grandchild2/>
  </Child>
</HOC>
```

I don't want to add any logic to the `Child` component, I want all the logic to be in the HOC. Is this possible?

Comment: And another XY problem. What is the actual real life pattern that you are trying to sovle with this?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to conditionally render grandchildren, that's pretty much it. I agree this would look like a XY problem, but I don't know how to explain it further. The application I've been working on with my team could use a HOC like that because we don't want to rewrite our current code that would be inside the HOC. I mean we could, and I could, but before we go down that road we wanted to explore the HOC possibility.
The logic is all in place to decide what grandchildren to render and what not, we just don't know how to render only one grandchild together with its parent.

Comment: Thats certainly impossible, because it's `Child`s decision wether it renders children or not. If you pass the Child in as in the code shown, for sure you can pass that conditionally.

Comment: Thanks! I was starting to come to the same conclusion. Just wanted to make sure. Rewriting it is!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,..

Logic like this is often better handled outside React, Redux is a popular choice.

But there is something in React called Context, there really meant for things like theming etc, but can also be used just to pass props / state down the React's Tree.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

example..  Below I have a `<Parent><Ignored><Child>`, and child is able to get a value that `<Parent>` has stored.  IOW: The prop/value has been passed from `Parent` To `Child`, bypassing `Ignored`.

ps.  The below example is React Hooks..

```js
const {useContext, createContext} = React;

const ParentContext = createContext();

function Child() {
  const parentValue = useContext(ParentContext);
  return <div>Child -> parent value = {parentValue}</div>;
}

function Ignored() {
  return <div><b>ignored</b><Child/></div>
}

function Parent() {
  return <ParentContext.Provider value={"value from parent"}>This is the parent..
    <Ignored/>
  </ParentContext.Provider>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Parent/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```